# ModelState.AddModelError here the error message I gave its not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

`ModelState.AddModelError` not working while posting the same user name to the database

Here if username not matching it will create a new user to the database

```
public ActionResult Signup(User user)
{

    using (var context = new dbTournamentEntities())
    {
        bool check = context.Users.Any(m => m.UserName == user.UserName);

        if (check)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Already Exist Try Different User Name");
        }
        else
        {
            var hashpass = HashPassword(user.Password);
            user.Password = hashpass;
            context.Users.Add(user);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Comment: After adding model error `ModelState.AddModelError` return your view, currently you are redirect your action so is not display any error

Answer (score 0):

The only reason your ModelState.AddModelError is not working if the variable check has a false value.

There are two possible cases that you can look for

1. If your database context has no value in user.
2. If your database context has same name user present then it is case sensitivity issue, try to make both uppercase and lowercase and then check for equality.

   ```cs
   bool check = context.Users.Any(m => m.UserName.ToUpper() == user.UserName.ToUpper());
   ```